# getting nsdictionary from the plist

Tags: iphone

I created a plist and the structure looks like:

```
Root - NSDictionary
  firstName - NSArray
  lastName - NSArray
```

I'm not sure how I access this data after I get the dictionary.  When I log the contents of my dictionary, like so

```
NSDictionary *presetsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.presetsDictionary = presetsDict;
for (NSString *key in self.presetsDictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key:%@, object:%@", key, [self.presetsDictionary objectForKey:key]);
```

I get

```
key:Root, object: {
lastName = (my lastName array, , , , ) // filled with the contents of my plist
firstName - (my firstName array, , , ,)
```

I was under the assumption that I would be able to get the lastName array and firstName array with something like

```
NSArray *fArray = [self.presetsDictionary objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

But that returns nil.  How do I get access to my NSDictionary in the plist?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your top-level object is a dictionary with one key named *Root* which contains your core dictionary (where your *firstName* and *lastName* keys live). So, to access this, you'd have to go through the object keyed by *Root* first. You can either get that dictionary and then access its keys, or use a keypath that includes the *Root* key:

```
// Accessing through the Root entry
NSDictionary* rootDict = [[self presetsDictionary] objectForKey:@"Root"];
NSArray* firstNames = [rootDict objectForKey:@"firstName"];
NSArray* lastNames  = [rootDict objectForKey:@"lastName"];

// Accessing using the keypath with Root
NSArray* firstNames = [[self presetsDictionary] valueForKeyPath:@"Root.firstName"];
NSArray* lastNames  = [[self presetsDictionary] valueForKeyPath:@"Root.lastName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do something like:
NSArray *fArray = [self.presetsDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"Root.firstName"];

In other words, it looks like you have nested dictionaries, and the only entry in the base dictionary is a single Key, Root, with the other data being the associated value.